# Local sequence not supported on LINQ to SQL. So how can I do this query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

That's my query:

```
var utenti = from User utente in db.User
             join amico in amiciParsed on new { utente.Nome, utente.Cognome } equals new { Nome = amico.first_name, Cognome = amico.last_name }
             select utente;
```

but I got that message:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

So how can I resolve the situation? Tried to store in a variable db.User, but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
var utenti = from User utente in db.User.AsEnumerable()
             join amico in amiciParsed on 
                 new { utente.Nome, utente.Cognome } equals 
                 new { Nome = amico.first_name, Cognome = amico.last_name }
             select utente;
```

But be careful if you want to extend the query, for example:

```
var utenti = from utente in (from User utente in db.User
                             where utente.Name.StartsWith(searchText)
                             select utente).AsEnumerable()
             join amico in amiciParsed on 
                 new { utente.Nome, utente.Cognome } equals 
                 new { Nome = amico.first_name, Cognome = amico.last_name }
             select utente;
```